# Loop over list of data frames using data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have 3 data frames that I'd like to run the same `data.table` function on. I could do this manually for each `data.frame` but I'd like to learn how to do it more efficiently.

Using the `data.table` package, I want to replace the contents of `col1` with the contents of `col2` only if `col1` contains "a". And I want to run this code over three different dataframes. On a single `data.frame`, this works fine:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b"), col2 = c("AA", "AA", "AA"))
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df1)
dt[grepl(pattern = "a", x = df1$col1),  col1 :=col2]
```

but I am lost trying to get this to run over multiple dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b"), col2 = c("AA", "AA", "AA"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c("b", "b", "a"), col2 = c("AA", "BB", "BB"))
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = c("b", "b", "b"), col2 = c("AA", "AA", "BB"))

library(data.table)
listdfs = list(df1, df2, df3)
for (i in dt[[]]) {
dt[[i]][grepl(pattern = "a", x = df[[i]]$col1), col1 := col2] }
```

But this obviously doesn't work because I have no clue what I'm doing with the for loop.  Any guidance/teaching would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looping through the `list`, then loop over the sequence of `list` and then do the assignment

```
listdfs = list(df1, df2, df3)
lapply(listdfs, setDT) # change the `data.frame` to `data.table`
for (i in seq_along(listdfs)) { # loop over sequence
   listdfs[[i]][grepl(pattern = "a", x = col1), col1 := col2]
 }
```

This would change the elements i.e. data.table with in the `listdfs` as well the object 'df1', 'df2', 'df3' itself as we didn't create any `copy`

```
df1
#   col1 col2
#1:   AA   AA  # change
#2:   AA   AA  # change
#3:    b   AA

df2
#   col1 col2
#1:    b   AA
#2:    b   BB
#3:   BB   BB   # change

df3
#   col1 col2
#1:    b   AA
#2:    b   AA
#3:    b   BB
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. is "seq_along()" standard for running through lists in a loop?

Comment: @moxed  `seq_along` can be for `vector`/data.frame/data.table column, list elements etc

Comment: @moxed The standard for running data.tables/data.frames through a loop, however, is to not run them through a loop. You can use `rbind` or `rbindlist` to get a single table, explained under the "combining" section of Gregor's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/